# Would a connected space contain a compact subspace

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I am trying to prove that in a connected space - $X$ , for every two elements of $X$ - say $a,b$ I can find a subspace of $X$ ( say $X'$ ) , such that$ X'$ contains a,b and is also connected, and compact.
I managed to do so if $X$ is metric or Hausdorff, or path connected. But for a general connected space I can't figure why it has to be true.
Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you mean by saying $X$ is open? All topological spaces are both open and closed in themselves by definition. And do you want $X'$ a proper subset?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I tried to specify my question. thanks for the remarks

Comment: Are you sure you want a proper subspace? Any connected subspace of $[0,1]$ containing $0$ and $1$ is the whole space.

Comment: Hi @NajibIdrissi. You are right, I don't necessarily need a proper subspace. But as i understand, because X is general, in case X is not compact, The subspace of X that i trying to find, must be a proper subspace. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R:x\ne0\text{ and }y=\sin\frac1x\}\cup\{(0,0)\}
$ with its induced topology as a subspace of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. Then $X$ is a connected (but not pathwise connected) metric space. There is no connected compact subspace of $X$ containing $\{(0,0)\}$ and any other point. If $x_1\lt0\lt x_2$, there is no connected compact subspace of $X$ containing $(x_1,\sin\frac1{x_1})$ and $(x_2,\sin\frac1{x_2})$.

This example is a variant of the [Topologist's Sine Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist's_sine_curve). The official version of the Topologist's Sine Curve, namely $\{(x,y)\in X:0\le x\le1\}$, works just as well as a counterexample here.

Comment: I'll add Wikipedia link: [Topologist's sine curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist's_sine_curve)

Comment: @MartinSleziak OK, thanks, I edited the link into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the space is path connected, you may take the smaller connected, compact space to be a path between the two points.

Comment: How could it not be true for the interval? Just take $X'=X$ in a connected compact space regardless of $a,b$.

Comment: @zibadawa I thought it was supposed to be a proper subspace. I'll edit. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, though possibly that is what he does want and failed to say so.

Comment: thanks guys, I do want X' to be a proper subspace. but @zibadawatimmy i don't see why X' = X should be also compact.

Comment: @zaich Because it's an assumption. If $X$ is compact and connected, then $X'=X$ works. Before you added the proper part in, that is.

Comment: @MattS thanks. but I don't know if X is a path connected space. that's where i stuck